# Scala: How to split a list into tuples in all possible ways

Tags: algorithm, scala, list, tuples, combinations

We have a storage with ONE place for every product. Every Order contains a set of products. The storage-worker has a trolley with room for a number N of Orders. 
For a list of Orders, find all possible solutions to solve the list.

(I am looking for an algorithm creating all possibilities to split a list into tuples, where the order of the tuples or elements does not matter.)

Here the example for a maximum of 2 orders (N=2) for a trolley.

```
val orders = List(1,2,3,4)
findAllSolutions(orders, 2)
List(
    Solution(Trolley(1,2),Trolley(3,4)), 
    Solution(Trolley(1,3),Trolley(2,4)), 
    Solution(Trolley(1,4),Trolley(2,3))
)
```

I could try it with

```
def tuplelize(lst: List[Int], tplLen) = List(1,2,3,4).permutations.map(l => l.grouped(tplLen).toList)
```

But this creates same results multiple times. E.g.

```
List((1,2),(3,4))
```

and

```
List((2,1),(4,3))
```

is the same.

A possibility is:

```
List(1,2,3,4).combinations(2).combinations(2).filter(_.flatten.toSet.size == 4)
```

But this seems very inefficient ...
Another example to clarify things:
given is a List(1,2,3,4,5) and i want to split it in Sub-Lists with maximal length of 3. Give all possible solutions with minimal count of Sub-Lists, so that every element can be found only one time in a Solution

```
Solution1: List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5))
Solution2: List(List(1,2,4),List(3,5))
Solution2: List(List(1,2,5),List(3,4))
...
```

an unwanted solution now, would be:

```
DoubleSolution: List(List(3,2,1),List(5,4))
```

Comment: Please refer this link http://vkostyukov.net/posts/combinatorial-algorithms-in-scala/

Comment: I don't understand what exactly `tplLen` is supposed to be. Could you give another example where not everything is 2x2x2x2? Your `tuplelize` doesn't seem to return iterable of lists of tuples, it returns iterable of lists of lists. Sure you don't want to rename it to "listlilize" instead? ;)

Comment: And stuff like `List(List(1,2), List(3,4))` and `List(List(3,4), List(1,2))` is also unwanted, because considered duplicate?

Comment: yes you got it ... so my "solution" combining two `combinations` calls will not work.

Comment: I think that it's the fact that `tplLen` does not have to divide the size of `lst` which makes it quite nasty...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin do you have a solution if tplLen divides lst?

Comment: @MeikoRachimow Yes, my previous proposal already did this for same-size partitions. But I updated my answer, it now solves it for the general case too.

Comment: Even though I've solved the combinatoric part, I still don't understand what the actual "trolley-problem" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Enumerating partitions with minimum number of subsets, such that all but at most one subsets have size at most `M`.

The code below does the following:

Given a list of distinct elements and some size `M`, it enumerates all partitions of type `List[List[Int]]` such that:

- every subset of the partition (represented by `List[Int]`) contains at most `M` elements
- the number of subsets is minimal
- there is at most one subset with less than `M` elements

That is, (almost) all subsets have size `M`, with at most one exception. The exception then has the size `N % M`, where `N` is the number of elements in the original list.

---

**Solution**

This turned out to be not entirely trivial. Especially the fact that the size of the subsets does not have to divide the number of elements was nasty, because it broke the symmetry in yet another way.

Here is a solution consisting of three stages:

1. Solve the problem for the case where size of partitions divides size of list (`sameSizePartitions`)
2. Solve the more general problem of generating partitions of arbitrary prescribed sizes (`prescribedSizePartition`)
3. Prepend a thin wrapper `maxSizePartitions` that computes the prescribed sizes and invokes `prescribedSizePartition`.

So, it was: generalize first, solve a different special case, use the different special case to solve the general case, use the general case to implement the desired function.

Here is what it looks like:

```
type Partition = List[List[Int]]

def sameSizePartitions(elems: List[Int], partSize: Int): List[Partition] = {
  def recHelper(unused: List[Int]): List[Partition] = {
    if (unused.size <= partSize) {
      List(List(unused))
    } else {
      val h :: t = unused
      (for {
        combination <- t.combinations(partSize - 1)
        tail <- recHelper(t filterNot combination.contains)
      } yield (h :: combination) :: tail).toList
    }
  }
  recHelper(elems)
}

/**
 * @param elems list with unique elements
 * @param sizes map (size -> numberOfPartitionsWithThisSize)
 */
def prescribedSizePartitions(elems: List[Int], sizes: Map[Int, Int]): List[Partition] = {
  if (sizes.isEmpty) {
    if (elems.isEmpty) List(Nil) 
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("sizes empty, but elems = " + elems)
  } else {
    val (size, numberOfPartitions) = sizes.head
    val numElementsNeededForPartitionsOfThisSize = size * numberOfPartitions
    for {
      elemSelection <- elems.combinations(numElementsNeededForPartitionsOfThisSize).toList
      tailPartition <- prescribedSizePartitions(elems.filterNot(elemSelection.contains), sizes - size)
      currSizePart <- sameSizePartitions(elemSelection, size)
    } yield currSizePart ++ tailPartition
  }
}

def maxSizePartitions(elems: List[Int], maxSize: Int): List[Partition] = {
  val n = elems.size
  val ofMaxSize = n / maxSize
  val restSize = n % maxSize
  if (restSize == 0) {
    sameSizePartitions(elems, maxSize)
  } else {
    prescribedSizePartitions(elems, Map(maxSize -> ofMaxSize, restSize -> 1))
  }
}
```

Examples:

```
maxSizePartitions((1 to 4).toList, 2) foreach println
maxSizePartitions((1 to 5).toList, 3) foreach println
maxSizePartitions((1 to 8).toList, 3) foreach println
```

Output:

```
List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 3), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 4), List(2, 3))

List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(2, 3))
List(List(2, 3, 4), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 3, 5), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 4, 5), List(1, 3))
List(List(3, 4, 5), List(1, 2))

List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 5, 6), List(7, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(3, 4, 6), List(7, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 6), List(3, 4, 5), List(7, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(2, 5, 6), List(7, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 4, 6), List(7, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 6), List(2, 4, 5), List(7, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(2, 3, 6), List(7, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 6), List(2, 3, 5), List(7, 8))
List(List(1, 5, 6), List(2, 3, 4), List(7, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 7), List(6, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 5, 7), List(6, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(3, 4, 7), List(6, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 7), List(3, 4, 5), List(6, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(2, 5, 7), List(6, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 4, 7), List(6, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 7), List(2, 4, 5), List(6, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(2, 3, 7), List(6, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 3, 5), List(6, 8))
List(List(1, 5, 7), List(2, 3, 4), List(6, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 8), List(6, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 5, 8), List(6, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(3, 4, 8), List(6, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 8), List(3, 4, 5), List(6, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(2, 5, 8), List(6, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 4, 8), List(6, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 8), List(2, 4, 5), List(6, 7))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(2, 3, 8), List(6, 7))
List(List(1, 4, 8), List(2, 3, 5), List(6, 7))
List(List(1, 5, 8), List(2, 3, 4), List(6, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 6, 7), List(5, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 6, 7), List(5, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 6), List(3, 4, 7), List(5, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 7), List(3, 4, 6), List(5, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(2, 6, 7), List(5, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 6), List(2, 4, 7), List(5, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 7), List(2, 4, 6), List(5, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 6), List(2, 3, 7), List(5, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 3, 6), List(5, 8))
List(List(1, 6, 7), List(2, 3, 4), List(5, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 6, 8), List(5, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 6, 8), List(5, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 6), List(3, 4, 8), List(5, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 8), List(3, 4, 6), List(5, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(2, 6, 8), List(5, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 6), List(2, 4, 8), List(5, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 8), List(2, 4, 6), List(5, 7))
List(List(1, 4, 6), List(2, 3, 8), List(5, 7))
List(List(1, 4, 8), List(2, 3, 6), List(5, 7))
List(List(1, 6, 8), List(2, 3, 4), List(5, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 7, 8), List(5, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 7, 8), List(5, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 7), List(3, 4, 8), List(5, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 8), List(3, 4, 7), List(5, 6))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(2, 7, 8), List(5, 6))
List(List(1, 3, 7), List(2, 4, 8), List(5, 6))
List(List(1, 3, 8), List(2, 4, 7), List(5, 6))
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 3, 8), List(5, 6))
List(List(1, 4, 8), List(2, 3, 7), List(5, 6))
List(List(1, 7, 8), List(2, 3, 4), List(5, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(5, 6, 7), List(4, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(3, 6, 7), List(4, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 6), List(3, 5, 7), List(4, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 7), List(3, 5, 6), List(4, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 6, 7), List(4, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 6), List(2, 5, 7), List(4, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 7), List(2, 5, 6), List(4, 8))
List(List(1, 5, 6), List(2, 3, 7), List(4, 8))
List(List(1, 5, 7), List(2, 3, 6), List(4, 8))
List(List(1, 6, 7), List(2, 3, 5), List(4, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(5, 6, 8), List(4, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(3, 6, 8), List(4, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 6), List(3, 5, 8), List(4, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 8), List(3, 5, 6), List(4, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 6, 8), List(4, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 6), List(2, 5, 8), List(4, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 8), List(2, 5, 6), List(4, 7))
List(List(1, 5, 6), List(2, 3, 8), List(4, 7))
List(List(1, 5, 8), List(2, 3, 6), List(4, 7))
List(List(1, 6, 8), List(2, 3, 5), List(4, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(5, 7, 8), List(4, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(3, 7, 8), List(4, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 7), List(3, 5, 8), List(4, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 8), List(3, 5, 7), List(4, 6))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 7, 8), List(4, 6))
List(List(1, 3, 7), List(2, 5, 8), List(4, 6))
List(List(1, 3, 8), List(2, 5, 7), List(4, 6))
List(List(1, 5, 7), List(2, 3, 8), List(4, 6))
List(List(1, 5, 8), List(2, 3, 7), List(4, 6))
List(List(1, 7, 8), List(2, 3, 5), List(4, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(6, 7, 8), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 2, 6), List(3, 7, 8), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 2, 7), List(3, 6, 8), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 2, 8), List(3, 6, 7), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 3, 6), List(2, 7, 8), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 3, 7), List(2, 6, 8), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 3, 8), List(2, 6, 7), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 6, 7), List(2, 3, 8), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 6, 8), List(2, 3, 7), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 7, 8), List(2, 3, 6), List(4, 5))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(5, 6, 7), List(3, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(4, 6, 7), List(3, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 6), List(4, 5, 7), List(3, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 7), List(4, 5, 6), List(3, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(2, 6, 7), List(3, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 6), List(2, 5, 7), List(3, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5, 6), List(3, 8))
List(List(1, 5, 6), List(2, 4, 7), List(3, 8))
List(List(1, 5, 7), List(2, 4, 6), List(3, 8))
List(List(1, 6, 7), List(2, 4, 5), List(3, 8))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(5, 6, 8), List(3, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(4, 6, 8), List(3, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 6), List(4, 5, 8), List(3, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 8), List(4, 5, 6), List(3, 7))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(2, 6, 8), List(3, 7))
List(List(1, 4, 6), List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 7))
List(List(1, 4, 8), List(2, 5, 6), List(3, 7))
List(List(1, 5, 6), List(2, 4, 8), List(3, 7))
List(List(1, 5, 8), List(2, 4, 6), List(3, 7))
List(List(1, 6, 8), List(2, 4, 5), List(3, 7))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(5, 7, 8), List(3, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(4, 7, 8), List(3, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 7), List(4, 5, 8), List(3, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 8), List(4, 5, 7), List(3, 6))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(2, 7, 8), List(3, 6))
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 6))
List(List(1, 4, 8), List(2, 5, 7), List(3, 6))
List(List(1, 5, 7), List(2, 4, 8), List(3, 6))
List(List(1, 5, 8), List(2, 4, 7), List(3, 6))
List(List(1, 7, 8), List(2, 4, 5), List(3, 6))
List(List(1, 2, 4), List(6, 7, 8), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 2, 6), List(4, 7, 8), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 2, 7), List(4, 6, 8), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 2, 8), List(4, 6, 7), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 4, 6), List(2, 7, 8), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 6, 8), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 4, 8), List(2, 6, 7), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 6, 7), List(2, 4, 8), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 6, 8), List(2, 4, 7), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 7, 8), List(2, 4, 6), List(3, 5))
List(List(1, 2, 5), List(6, 7, 8), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 2, 6), List(5, 7, 8), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 2, 7), List(5, 6, 8), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 2, 8), List(5, 6, 7), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 5, 6), List(2, 7, 8), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 5, 7), List(2, 6, 8), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 5, 8), List(2, 6, 7), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 6, 7), List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 6, 8), List(2, 5, 7), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 7, 8), List(2, 5, 6), List(3, 4))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7), List(2, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(4, 6, 7), List(2, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 6), List(4, 5, 7), List(2, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 7), List(4, 5, 6), List(2, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(3, 6, 7), List(2, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 6), List(3, 5, 7), List(2, 8))
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(3, 5, 6), List(2, 8))
List(List(1, 5, 6), List(3, 4, 7), List(2, 8))
List(List(1, 5, 7), List(3, 4, 6), List(2, 8))
List(List(1, 6, 7), List(3, 4, 5), List(2, 8))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 8), List(2, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(4, 6, 8), List(2, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 6), List(4, 5, 8), List(2, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 8), List(4, 5, 6), List(2, 7))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(3, 6, 8), List(2, 7))
List(List(1, 4, 6), List(3, 5, 8), List(2, 7))
List(List(1, 4, 8), List(3, 5, 6), List(2, 7))
List(List(1, 5, 6), List(3, 4, 8), List(2, 7))
List(List(1, 5, 8), List(3, 4, 6), List(2, 7))
List(List(1, 6, 8), List(3, 4, 5), List(2, 7))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(5, 7, 8), List(2, 6))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(4, 7, 8), List(2, 6))
List(List(1, 3, 7), List(4, 5, 8), List(2, 6))
List(List(1, 3, 8), List(4, 5, 7), List(2, 6))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(3, 7, 8), List(2, 6))
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(3, 5, 8), List(2, 6))
List(List(1, 4, 8), List(3, 5, 7), List(2, 6))
List(List(1, 5, 7), List(3, 4, 8), List(2, 6))
List(List(1, 5, 8), List(3, 4, 7), List(2, 6))
List(List(1, 7, 8), List(3, 4, 5), List(2, 6))
List(List(1, 3, 4), List(6, 7, 8), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 3, 6), List(4, 7, 8), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 3, 7), List(4, 6, 8), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 3, 8), List(4, 6, 7), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 4, 6), List(3, 7, 8), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(3, 6, 8), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 4, 8), List(3, 6, 7), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 6, 7), List(3, 4, 8), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 6, 8), List(3, 4, 7), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 7, 8), List(3, 4, 6), List(2, 5))
List(List(1, 3, 5), List(6, 7, 8), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 3, 6), List(5, 7, 8), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 3, 7), List(5, 6, 8), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 3, 8), List(5, 6, 7), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 5, 6), List(3, 7, 8), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 5, 7), List(3, 6, 8), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 5, 8), List(3, 6, 7), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 6, 7), List(3, 5, 8), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 6, 8), List(3, 5, 7), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 7, 8), List(3, 5, 6), List(2, 4))
List(List(1, 4, 5), List(6, 7, 8), List(2, 3))
List(List(1, 4, 6), List(5, 7, 8), List(2, 3))
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(5, 6, 8), List(2, 3))
List(List(1, 4, 8), List(5, 6, 7), List(2, 3))
List(List(1, 5, 6), List(4, 7, 8), List(2, 3))
List(List(1, 5, 7), List(4, 6, 8), List(2, 3))
List(List(1, 5, 8), List(4, 6, 7), List(2, 3))
List(List(1, 6, 7), List(4, 5, 8), List(2, 3))
List(List(1, 6, 8), List(4, 5, 7), List(2, 3))
List(List(1, 7, 8), List(4, 5, 6), List(2, 3))
List(List(2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7), List(1, 8))
List(List(2, 3, 5), List(4, 6, 7), List(1, 8))
List(List(2, 3, 6), List(4, 5, 7), List(1, 8))
List(List(2, 3, 7), List(4, 5, 6), List(1, 8))
List(List(2, 4, 5), List(3, 6, 7), List(1, 8))
List(List(2, 4, 6), List(3, 5, 7), List(1, 8))
List(List(2, 4, 7), List(3, 5, 6), List(1, 8))
List(List(2, 5, 6), List(3, 4, 7), List(1, 8))
List(List(2, 5, 7), List(3, 4, 6), List(1, 8))
List(List(2, 6, 7), List(3, 4, 5), List(1, 8))
List(List(2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 8), List(1, 7))
List(List(2, 3, 5), List(4, 6, 8), List(1, 7))
List(List(2, 3, 6), List(4, 5, 8), List(1, 7))
List(List(2, 3, 8), List(4, 5, 6), List(1, 7))
List(List(2, 4, 5), List(3, 6, 8), List(1, 7))
List(List(2, 4, 6), List(3, 5, 8), List(1, 7))
List(List(2, 4, 8), List(3, 5, 6), List(1, 7))
List(List(2, 5, 6), List(3, 4, 8), List(1, 7))
List(List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 4, 6), List(1, 7))
List(List(2, 6, 8), List(3, 4, 5), List(1, 7))
List(List(2, 3, 4), List(5, 7, 8), List(1, 6))
List(List(2, 3, 5), List(4, 7, 8), List(1, 6))
List(List(2, 3, 7), List(4, 5, 8), List(1, 6))
List(List(2, 3, 8), List(4, 5, 7), List(1, 6))
List(List(2, 4, 5), List(3, 7, 8), List(1, 6))
List(List(2, 4, 7), List(3, 5, 8), List(1, 6))
List(List(2, 4, 8), List(3, 5, 7), List(1, 6))
List(List(2, 5, 7), List(3, 4, 8), List(1, 6))
List(List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 4, 7), List(1, 6))
List(List(2, 7, 8), List(3, 4, 5), List(1, 6))
List(List(2, 3, 4), List(6, 7, 8), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 3, 6), List(4, 7, 8), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 3, 7), List(4, 6, 8), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 3, 8), List(4, 6, 7), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 4, 6), List(3, 7, 8), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 4, 7), List(3, 6, 8), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 4, 8), List(3, 6, 7), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 6, 7), List(3, 4, 8), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 6, 8), List(3, 4, 7), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 7, 8), List(3, 4, 6), List(1, 5))
List(List(2, 3, 5), List(6, 7, 8), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 3, 6), List(5, 7, 8), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 3, 7), List(5, 6, 8), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 3, 8), List(5, 6, 7), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 5, 6), List(3, 7, 8), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 5, 7), List(3, 6, 8), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 6, 7), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 6, 7), List(3, 5, 8), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 6, 8), List(3, 5, 7), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 7, 8), List(3, 5, 6), List(1, 4))
List(List(2, 4, 5), List(6, 7, 8), List(1, 3))
List(List(2, 4, 6), List(5, 7, 8), List(1, 3))
List(List(2, 4, 7), List(5, 6, 8), List(1, 3))
List(List(2, 4, 8), List(5, 6, 7), List(1, 3))
List(List(2, 5, 6), List(4, 7, 8), List(1, 3))
List(List(2, 5, 7), List(4, 6, 8), List(1, 3))
List(List(2, 5, 8), List(4, 6, 7), List(1, 3))
List(List(2, 6, 7), List(4, 5, 8), List(1, 3))
List(List(2, 6, 8), List(4, 5, 7), List(1, 3))
List(List(2, 7, 8), List(4, 5, 6), List(1, 3))
List(List(3, 4, 5), List(6, 7, 8), List(1, 2))
List(List(3, 4, 6), List(5, 7, 8), List(1, 2))
List(List(3, 4, 7), List(5, 6, 8), List(1, 2))
List(List(3, 4, 8), List(5, 6, 7), List(1, 2))
List(List(3, 5, 6), List(4, 7, 8), List(1, 2))
List(List(3, 5, 7), List(4, 6, 8), List(1, 2))
List(List(3, 5, 8), List(4, 6, 7), List(1, 2))
List(List(3, 6, 7), List(4, 5, 8), List(1, 2))
List(List(3, 6, 8), List(4, 5, 7), List(1, 2))
List(List(3, 7, 8), List(4, 5, 6), List(1, 2))
```

I hope I solved the right problem this time?

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3,4)
// l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val setList = list.toSet.subsets(2).toList
// setList: List[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = List(Set(1, 2), Set(1, 3), Set(1, 4), Set(2, 3), Set(2, 4), Set(3, 4))

scala> val tupleList = setList.map(_.toList).map({ case List(x, y) => (x, y)})
// tupleList: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4))
```

Comment: sorry, not what i want, please see my example
List(
    List((1,2),(3,4)), 
    List((1,3),(2,4)), 
    List((1,4),(2,3))
)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so far this is what I've got:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4).permutations.map(x => x.sliding(2,2).toSet).flatten.map(z => z.sorted).toSet
res24: scala.collection.immutable.Set[List[Int]] = Set(List(3, 4), List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(1, 4), List(2, 4), List(1, 3))
```

Which I think is closer to the desired result but not quite in the format expected.

EDIT:

So far so good:

```
scala> val resultSet = List(1,2,3,4).permutations.map(x => x.sliding(2,2).toSet).flatten.map(z => z.sorted).toSet.toList
resultSet: List[List[Int]] = List(List(3, 4), List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(1, 4), List(2, 4), List(1, 3))

scala> resultSet.reverse.sliding(2,2).toList
res1: List[List[List[Int]]] = List(List(List(1, 3), List(2, 4)), List(List(1, 4), List(2, 3)), List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4)))
```

Yeah this only works if you want tuples of size 2 so not very dynamic. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: hi, thank you. but the solution do not work for other parameter: e.g. sliding(3,3) with a List 1 to 9